# MySql PHP Combine Select Queries 1

Tags: php, mysql

Query 1

```
SELECT * FROM `student_1` WHERE location like '%php%'
```

Query 2

```
SELECT * FROM `student_4` WHERE keyskill like '%php%'
```

I want to combine these two tables in to one code and result

Answer (score 0):

Use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

```
SELECT * FROM student_1 WHERE location like '%php%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM student_4 WHERE keyskill like '%php%'
```

as long as the columns in the two tables match

Comment: "SELECT statements have a different number of columns" mysql replies this error

Comment: Then make sure you modify the selects to return an equal number of columns, even if you have to add some dummy NULLs to one of the queries.... read the docs link to get an explanation of how columns should be matched.... but that's something you have to do yourself, because you haven't posted any details of your tables

Comment: Read the Friendly documentation that I linked for you, or provide details of your table structures and the columns that you actually want to get from each when you execute the query

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT *
    FROM student_1
    ) where condition,
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM student_4
    ) where condition
)
```

Comment: some syntax err is there pls clarify it

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT  ( SELECT * FROM student_1) where location like '%php%',(SELECT *FROM student_4) where keyskill like '%php%'
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where location like '%php%',(SELECT *FROM student_4) where keyskill like '%php%'' at line 1

Comment: can u grow it using joins

Comment: Documentation #1064 error because the query doesn't match your mysql server version, check your mysql version and modify the query it should work then